# No se centra el contenido del formulario en css

Tags: css, html5

Llevo un rato intentando centrar el contenido del sidebar en una web en html y css y no sé porque cada elemento aparece movido respecto al otro. Quiero que estén todos centrados. He intentado usar text-align:center y no queda centrado ni el h2 ni el h3. Quedan cada uno en una posicion distinta. En el formulario el primer input aparace desplazado hacia la derecha respecto al de abajo.

```css
#sidebar {
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
}

#sidebar h2 {
  width: 100%;
  
}
#sidebar h3 {
text-align: center;}

#formulario {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;

}

#campo1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  

}
#campo2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  
}

#footer {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar">
       <h2>barra lateral</h2>
      <h3>formulario</h3>
      <form action="">
        <div id="campo1"><label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"></div>
        <div id="campo2"><label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></div>
        
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar">


      </form>
     
    
    </aside>
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. En el snippet se ven centrados... Pero, ejecutando en pantalla completa, sí se logra ver lo que mencionás acerca de los `input`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal parece que lo deseas en verdad es que los input se alineen por separado a una misma altura, te presentó una solución agregando la etiqueta *`<table>`* y con ello *`<th>`* y *`<tr>`*

[Información de etiqueta table](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

HTML

```
<aside id="sidebar">
       <h2>barra lateral</h2>
      <h3>formulario</h3>
      <form action="">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
        <div id="campo1"><label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
          </th><th>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"></div>
          </th>
          </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <div id="campo2"><label for="email">Email:</label>
          </th><th>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></div>
  </th></tr>
<th>
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </th>
        </table>
      </form>
    </aside>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 600px;
}
#sidebar h2 {
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar h3 {
text-align: center;
}
#formulario {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Adjunto resultado, con la implementación de table: https://codepen.io/mabmab159/pen/KKXKwGX

Saludos